# Visual Studio Installer does not include satellite resource assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, installation, assemblies, satellite

I have a VS2008 installer project which installs a .NET Windows Service.  One of the service's dependencies is a .NET assembly which has localized resources in the form of a satellite assembly.  The installer is not packaging or installing the satellite assembly for some reason and the service will consequently not start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you right click the project in solution explorer and choose View > Files you can see which files will be installed to the target machine.

It may be as simple as adding the localized resource file as an output in the Target Machine's Application directory.

However, check the installer project's dependencies and make sure that all of the projects (main assembly and otherwise) are listed.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Add "localized resources" is indeed on the context menu for the VSI project.  Thanks!